# Conversion of Oracle Query to Hibernate query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, hql

Please Help to solve this issue..
I need to count how many rules are there associated to a group_id. In that I need rules_id of count = 1
Rule is hibernate mapped Table.
Group is hibernate mapped Table.
ALERT_RULE_GROUP is a JoinTable which is one-to-many.

Query which is giving me the correct Result:

```
select rule_id from ALERT_RULE_GROUP where rule_id in(select rule_id from ALERT_RULE_GROUP where GROUP_ID=850) group by rule_id having count(*)=1;
```

I am not getting ALERT_RULE_GROUP is not mapped..
Please help me to convert this to HQL..

Comment: I think hibernate doesnt do subqueries you might need a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to map the relation which ALERT_RULE_GROUP represents in Hibernate before you can proceed. That is what Hibernate is trying to tell you.

To do this, add a ManyToMany or a OneToMany or whatever it is between Role and Group and specify the join table name with a @JoinTable(name=ALERT_RULE_GROUP)  annotation.

Comment: @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name="ALERT_RULE_GROUP", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="RULE_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID") })
 private Set<Groups> groups = new HashSet<Groups>();

Comment: it is mentioned in Rule.java

Comment: Aha. You already had it mapped. Sorry about that. Havent tried   querying directly into a join table. What about mapping the table again in a separate entity: "AlertRuleGroup". You could there map the ids as ints and perform the query. If you dislike this and querying join tables is not possible, why not just stick with the SQL?